# Plotting multiple variables in y-axis over time

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following dataset from the time frame 02.01.2007-30.12.2016, which consists of two rates and the difference of these exact rates:

```
head(risk_free_rate_comparison)

   Dates `       Swap rate` `Sovereign bond yield rate` `Swap rate - Sovereign bond yield rate`
  <dttm>         <dbl>       <dbl>                       <dbl>
1 2007-01-02     408.9       380.9568                    27.9432
2 2007-01-03     410.3       380.4535                    29.8465
3 2007-01-04     409.2       381.3993                    27.8007
4 2007-01-05     414.3       385.0663                    29.2337
5 2007-01-08     413.1       384.2545                    28.8455
6 2007-01-09     415.5       384.9770                    30.5230
```

I would like to plot the Dates on the x-axis in order to display the end of each year on the x-axis: 2007-2016.

And to have the three other variables, which are denoted in basispoints, on the y-axis, with lines that go through the datapoints. It would be nice to have different line styles, for example one solid, one dashed and one dotted. 
Last I would like to have a legend on the side of the plot which shows the variable names.

More or less like in this example just without the grid:

[image: plot example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple and quick plots use `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(risk_free_rate_comparison, "Dates")
d$Dates <- as.Date(d$Dates)
ggplot(d, aes(Dates, value, color = variable, linetype = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

`reshape2::melt` transforms (groups your data). In this case by `Date` as you want to put it on x-axis. `theme_classic()` is `ggplot2` theme without grid.

[image]

Comment: Sorry one more question, is it possible to remove the word variable in the legend and move the legend under the plot?

Comment: @rbonac happy to help :-)